# Possible outputs using fork()

Tags: c, fork

In the following code:

```
int num = 0;
void signal_hand(int sig) {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_hand);
    num++;
    printf("num = %d\n", num);
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_hand);
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    pid_t child = fork();
    switch(child) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            num = 0;
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            break;
        default:
            num = num + 1;
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output could be only:

```
num = 1  
num = 2  
num = 4
```

or:

```
num = 1  
num = 3  
num = 4
```

But I don't understand why, If the parent runs first so that after printing `num = 1` then `num = 3` and then if the child is running so that `num = 0` and then printing `num = 1`, how it's possible that num will be 4, I don't get the 2 cases. (When the parent runs first and when the child runs first)

Comment: `num = 0` in child does not affect that in parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the beginning there is only one process with `num` set to 0. Afterwards your first signal arrives:

```c
int main() {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_hand);
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
```

This naturally increases `num` by 1 and prints it, as this is how you defined your signal handler. This is where `num = 1` comes from.

Afterwards you call `fork`. The process is copied, along with most of its resources which includes memory. The variables reside in the memory of the process, which means that they are copied as well. So now you have 2 processes, each with its own copy of `num` which are independent on each other. Both copies of `num` are equal to 1 as this was the value at the time when `fork` was called. Additionally, each process will have a different PID - the original process will retain its PID that you saved in the `main` function in the `pid` variable, and the copy will have a new PID. Keep that in mind as it is important for the example.

Now, according to your switch statement, each copy of the process will call different code:

```c
switch(child) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        num = 0;
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        break;
    default:
        num = num + 1;
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        break;
}
```

The copy of the process will execute the branch of the switch statement under the `case 0:`. It will reset `num` to 0 - but only its own copy! The copy of the original process will not be touched as they are independent. Then, it will fire a signal in the original process, not in itself. This is cause you use the `pid` variable that contains the PID of the original process. This will cause the signal handler to run, again, in the parent, which increases the `num` variable by 1 and prints it. At the same time, the original process will run the `default:` branch of the switch statement, increasing its copy of `num` by 1 and firing another signal in itself.

These two signals are responsible for `num = 3` or `num = 2` as well as `num = 4`. The middle result will be different based on a race condition in your code. With how you have written your code, you do not know whether the parent executes `num = num + 1` or the child executes its `kill` first. If the increment is first, then the value will be 3, if the `kill` is first, the value will be 2.